# Replace characters to make international letters (diacritics)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to emulate the way an international keyboard works. If you use one of the [dead keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) followed by a letter, it combines them into the corresponding character. For example, typing in `` `a `` would result in `à` and `^o` results in `ô`, etc.

I can't seem to get my regex to work properly (I suck at regex!), but this is what I have so far ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/jMTjL/)):

```
var txt = "Replacing 'a ^u ~n 'e ^I 'c",

    combos = {
        'a': ['à', 'á', 'ä', 'â'],
        'A': ['À', 'Á', 'Ä', 'Â'],
        'e': ['è', 'é', 'ë', 'ê'],
        'E': ['È', 'É', 'Ë', 'Ê'],
        'i': ['ì', 'í', 'ï', 'î'],
        'I': ['Ì', 'Í', 'Ï', 'Î'],
        'o': ['ò', 'ó', 'ö', 'ô'],
        'O': ['Ò', 'Ó', 'Ö', 'Ô'],
        'u': ['ù', 'ú', 'ü', 'û'],
        'U': ['Ù', 'Ú', 'Ü', 'Û'],
        'y': 'ý',
        'Y': 'Ý',
        'c': 'ç',
        'C': 'Ç',
        'n': 'ñ',
        'N': 'Ñ'
    },

    bslash = /`[(aeiou)]/gi,
    fslash = /\'[(aeiouyc)]/gi,
    ddots = /\"[(aeiou)]/gi,
    caret = /\^[(aeiou)]/gi,
    tidle = /~[(n)]/gi;

// global match
if (txt.match(/[`|\'|\"|\^|~][aeiouycn]/i)) {

    // back slash - replace `a with à
    if (bslash.test(txt)) {
        txt = txt.replace(bslash, function(r) {
            // r contains the `, so remove it with a slice
            return combos[r.slice(-1)][0];
        });
    }

    // forward slash - replace 'a with á, etc
    if (fslash.test(txt)) {
        txt = txt.replace(fslash, function(r) {
            r = r.slice(-1);
            return (r == 'c' || r == 'y') ? combos[r][0] : combos[r][3];
        });
    }

    // double dots - replace `a with à
    if (ddots.test(txt)) {
        txt = txt.replace(ddots, function(r) {
            return combos[r.slice(-1)][4];
        });
    }

    // caret - replace ^a with â
    if (caret.test(txt)) {
        txt = txt.replace(caret, function(r) {
            return combos[r.slice(-1)][3];
        });
    }

    // tidle - replace ~n with ñ
    if (tidle.test(txt)) {
        txt = txt.replace(tidle, function(r) {
            return combos[r.slice(-1)][0];
        });
    }

    document.write(txt);
}
```

Also, if you know of a more efficient method to do this same thing, I've love to hear it!

---

I updated my answer above with the problem Aefxx found - thanks! But I decided to go with Kenny's method as it is cleaner, thanks all! :)  ([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/jMTjL/1/))

```
var txt = "Replacing 'a ^u ~n 'e ^I 'c",

 combos = {
  '`' :{ a:'à', A:'À', e:'è', E:'È', i:'ì', I:'Ì', o:'ò', O:'Ò', u:'ù', U:'Ù' },
  "'" :{ a:'á', A:'Á', e:'é', E:'É', i:'í', I:'Í', o:'ó', O:'Ó', u:'ú', U:'Ú', y:'ý', Y:'Ý', c:'ç', C:'Ç' },
  '"' :{ a:'ä', A:'Ä', e:'ë', E:'Ë', i:'ï', I:'Ï', o:'ö', O:'Ö', u:'ü', U:'Ü' },
  '^' :{ a:'â', A:'Â', e:'ê', E:'Ê', i:'î', I:'Î', o:'ô', O:'Ô', u:'û', U:'Û' },
  '~' :{ n:'ñ', N:'Ñ' }
 };

 txt = txt.replace(/([`\'~\^\"])([a-z])/ig, function(s, accent, letter){
   return (accent in combos) ? combos[accent][letter] || s : s;
 });

 document.write(txt);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var txt = "Replacing 'a ^u ~n 'e ^I 'c";

var combos = {
   '^': {a: 'â', A: 'Â', e: 'ê', E: 'Ê', ...},
   "'": {a: 'á', ...},
   ...
};

return txt.replace(/([`'~^"])([a-z])/ig, function(s, accent, letter){
  if (accent in combos) {
    return combos[accent][letter] || s;
  }
  return s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I thought about using the accents as the key, but I thought the object would be bigger than what I already had. Turns out it's cleaner :)

Answer (score 2):

A more complete approach is the JavaScript port of the Apache Lucene ASCII Folding algorithm you can find at https://github.com/mplatt/fold-to-ascii-js
It handles the diacritics you mentioned and many more characters.

Comment: +1 What I was working on does the reverse - type in `^o` and get `ô`; but that's still very nice work! I'll look into including it with my [tablesorter project](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortlocalecompare) ;)

Comment: @Mottie Thanks! I can't take the credit though. All the "heavy lifting" in terms of creating the replacement table has been done by the Apache Lucene developers. All I did was porting it to JS.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, problem solved. You made a mistake many of use do (me included) quite often. Calling `replace` on a string without assignment won't work, you're just replacing into the wild.

```
...
// Notice the assignment of the replaced text here !!!
txt = txt.replace(bslash, function(r) {
        // r contains the `, so remove it with a slice
        return combos[r.slice(-1)][0];
    });
```

Comment: Thanks that was the problem! But I'm going to go with Kenny's answer as it is much more efficient. I still appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Must a regex be used? it seems easier to just go through the entire string. Well, that would be like coding the automaton by hand instead, but using the table already defined by `combos`